# Curious behavior of :%normal g_lD (remove trailing spaces in file)

Tags: command-line, normal-mode

This is a noob attempt of mine, to remove trailing spaces in a file. The first attempt is:

```
:%normal g_lD
```

It worked, and I was happy. Then I tried it on a single line where there was no trailing whitespace using normal mode command

```
g_lD
```

Not too surprisingly, this deleted the last valid,non-blank character of the line since there is no trailing whitespace on this line.

Now my question is this -

> why did my first command succeed on all lines?
>
> (it did not delete the last non-blank characters on all those lines with no trailing whitespace)

Comment: Here’s an alternative solution for deleting trailing white space: `:%s/\s\+$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the last sentence in `:help :normal`:

> Execution stops when an error is encountered.

In this context, trying to go right at the end of the line is considered an error, so the `D` isn’t carried out.

This "stop on error" behaviour is also visible in various other places where Vim plays a macro. e.g. mappings, [recordings](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#q).

In particular, it's useful for terminating a recursive macro when it's done all its work.

If for some reason you *need* execution to continue when errors occur, you can use [`:silent!`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Asilent), which will cause Vim to ignore the errors and carry on executing the keystrokes:

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally, one less burden of my unresolved curiosities.

Comment: is it worth pointing out that `:silent! normal` negates this behavior?

Comment: @Mass It's worth pointing it out to me! (I wasn't aware of this.)